# ImportError: No module named caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, anaconda, caffe, conda

I am trying to run [Google Research's DeepDream code](http://googleresearch.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/deepdream-code-example-for-visualizing.html) on a mac running OSx 10.9.5.
There are a few dependencies that I had to install. I am using the Anaconda distribution of python and I made sure that I have all the packages required.

The hardest thing was to install Caffe. I have ATLAS installed using fink. Then I have compiled caffe and pycaffe. When I ran 'make runtest' all tests passed. I also ran 'make distribute'.

When I run [the notebook released from Google](https://github.com/google/deepdream), I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8200bcb1df23> in <module>()
      7 from google.protobuf import text_format
      8 
----> 9 import caffe
     10 
     11 def showarray(a, fmt='jpeg'):

ImportError: No module named caffe
```

How can this be? What can I try to do to fix it?

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/720 Try add  PYTHONPATH to your .bashrc file

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but I had the same problem. I found using the Vagrant build [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/deepdream/comments/3c2s0v/newbie_guide_for_windows/) worked smoothly though.

Comment: @martic that actually worked... which led me to another problem. See my new question: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31393897/importerror-dlopen-library-not-open"

Comment: Can you `import caffe2` . `caffe` is deprecated

Comment: @Tessaracter I asked this question 4.5 years ago. I should probably take it down