# ImportError: dlopen(...) library not open

Tags: python, macos, neural-network, anaconda, caffe

I am trying to run [Google Research's DeepDream code](http://googleresearch.blogspot.co.uk/2015/07/deepdream-code-example-for-visualizing.html) on a mac running OSx 10.9.5.
There are a few dependencies that I had to install. I am using the Anaconda distribution of python and I made sure that I have all the packages required.

The hardest thing was to install Caffe. I have ATLAS installed using fink. Then I have compiled caffe and pycaffe. When I ran 'make runtest' all tests passed. I also ran 'make distribute'.

When I run [the notebook released from Google](https://github.com/google/deepdream), I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-453033db464f> in <module>()
     11 
     12 
---> 13 import caffe
     14 
     15 

/Users/Andrea/caffe/python/caffe/__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver
      2 from ._caffe import set_mode_cpu, set_mode_gpu, set_device, Layer, get_solver
      3 from .proto.caffe_pb2 import TRAIN, TEST
      4 from .classifier import Classifier
      5 from .detector import Detector

/Users/Andrea/caffe/python/caffe/pycaffe.py in <module>()
     11 import numpy as np
     12 
---> 13 from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver
     14 import caffe.io
     15 

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Andrea/caffe/python/caffe/_caffe.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcudart.7.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/Andrea/caffe/python/caffe/_caffe.so
  Reason: image not found
```

What can I do to fix this?

---

[image: here is the screendump requested in a comment]

Answer (score 1):

libcudart.7.0.dylib is a GPU related library.

Does the machine you're running on have a GPU? If not, then you need to specify CPU mode in Makefile.config for caffe.

If you do have a GPU, then please take a look here.
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/779

Comment: I deleted the folder containing caffe and recompiled the whole thing with the CPU mode on. It now gives me this error:

     ImportError: dlopen(/Users/Andrea/caffe-master/python/caffe/_caffe.so, 2): Library not loaded: libhdf5_hl.10.dylib

Comment: Could you share more on when this happens? A screen dump of what you see on the screen would be useful. Is this happening when you make all or make pycaffe?

Comment: This is happening when I run the first block of code in dream.ipynb downloaded here https://github.com/google/deepdream, as written in question body.

Comment: That is, after I make clean, make all, make test, make runtest, make pycaffe and make distribute in the folder where caffe is.

Comment: python/caffe/_caffe.so errors are usually caused when caffe isnt in the PYTHONPATH. Like I said, it's a bit hard to be more helpful when I don't see what exactly you did to get here. Sorry can't be more helpful

Comment: Did it help? Take a look here https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/720 and also here http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html

Comment: I had already done that before asking the question! Python definitely finds caffe, the problem is about the this libhdf5_hl.10.dylib